# Find max group value without using Max()/Greatest() function

Tags: sql, group-by, max

I've been trying to do this for hours but I keep getting a null result. So far I have got the following table by running a query

`select count(posts) from dbtable group by user`

```
user | posts
_____________
a   |   3
b   |   7
c   |   2
d   |   1
e   |   1
```

How can i display the user with the maximum posts without using max()/greatest() or even LIMIT functions. The original table I ran the above query on had a list of all posts along with the user who submitted each post, i just grouped them up.

Comment: Please show your code which have you tried

Comment: What do you have against limit, max or greatest?

Comment: Select top(1) * FROM (your aggregate ORDER BY [posts] DESC)

Comment: select TOP 1 [user],count(posts) as postcount from tablename group by [user] ORDER BY postcount desc

Comment: i dont have anything against max() :) , im solving a practice test paper for my exams and on this question it says im not supposed to use max or greatest, so im pretty much supposed to stick to basic sql operations. I would guess that top would be out of the question as well.

Answer (score 2, accepted):

```
select * from 
(
select user,count(posts) cnt from dbtable 
group by user
) t1
left join 
(
select user,count(posts) cnt from dbtable 
group by user
) t2 on (t1.user<>t2.user) and (t1.cnt<t2.cnt)

where t2.cnt is null
```

[SQLFiddle demo](http://sqlfiddle.com/#!2/5feda/5)

Comment: WOW, this worked, ive been trying to use a self join all this time, but i guess this is better, Thanks!

Answer (score 0):

Here is another solution which works, but is awfully slow for bigger tables., I tested it with a small set of 48 entries and it is fast enough, but on a table with 200.000 records it runs for hours without completing.:)

```
select *
from
(
    select distinct column
    from table t0
    join table t1 on t0.key = t1.key
    where t0.column > t1.column
    order by t0.column desc
)
where rownum <= 1
;
```